# Random number generation with pyCUDA

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I want to generate random numbers with `pyCUDA`.

To this end, I'm using the following code, which I'm running on the Kaggle virtual machine:

```
import numpy           as np
import time

import pycuda.gpuarray as     gpuarray
import pycuda.driver   as     cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler   import SourceModule

N = 10

from pycuda.curandom import XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator
rng   = XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator()
d_x   = rng.gen_uniform((N,), dtype = np.float32)
```

My question is on how do I feed the random number generator with a seed.

At the [pyCUDA documentation page](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html), it says that

> class `pycuda.curandom.XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator(seed_getter=None, offset=0)`
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> `seed_getter` – a function that, given an
>   integer count, will yield an `int32` GPUArray of seeds.
>
> `offset` –
>   Starting index into the XORWOW sequence, given seed.

What is an example of the `seed_getter` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curandom` module has two built-in functions for generating random seeds:

1. [`seed_getter_uniform`](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html#pycuda.curandom.seed_getter_uniform) which will return an array length N initialized with a single random seed, and
2. [`seed_getter_unique`](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html#pycuda.curandom.seed_getter_unique) which will return an array initialized with N different random seeds.

Use one or the other depending on whether you want all internal generator instances to used the same seed or a unique seed.

Comment: Thanks talonmies, but I tried to use `rng   = XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator(pycuda.curandom.seed_getter_uniform(N))`, but it throws the following error: `TypeError: 'GPUArray' object is not callable`.

Comment: You supply the *function* to the generator, not the output. The generator handles seed generation itself

Comment: Right: `rng   = XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator(pycuda.curandom.seed_getter_uniform)`. Thanks.